# How do i assign a class to a html image with css?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, styles

This is the html part:

```css
.bild{
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
    <img class = "bild" src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" alt="the google logo" > 
</div>
```

They do not seem to "understand" each other, as the image does not change.

Comment: This seems to work as expected, what is it you expect it to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The example with the picture you gave works. It could be that you have not noticed any difference. Here is another example where I colour a text with a class:

```css
.color {
  color: red;
}

.colorHeader {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="color">This text is red!</p>

<h1 class="colorHeader">This header is red!</h1>
```

you could also change this:

```css
.color {
  color: red;
}

.colorHeader {
  color: red;
}
```

to this:

```css
.color, .colorHeader {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some extra spaces in your HTML, but the output still works as defined in your CSS. I recommend specifying the desired width or height and using auto on the other in this case.

```css
.bild {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="bild" src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" alt="the google logo"> 
</div>
```